# Need ASP code for a simple form - radio buttons redirect to urls

Tags: asp.net, forms, radio-button

Can someone direct me to an example of asp code that will process a form which has only radio buttons? The functionality: When a radio button is checked and submit is clicked the user will be redirected to specific url. onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';" Will not do the trick here. We have to wait until "submit" is clicked.

```
<form name="input" action="the_code_you_are_helping_me_with.asp" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="option1" value="1" />option1<br />
<input type="radio" name="option2" value="2" />option2<br />
<input type="radio" name="option3" value="3" />option3<br />
<input type="radio" name="option4" value="4" />option4<br />
<input type="radio" name="option5" value="5" />option5<br />


<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Thanks in advance,

dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/89s6R/3/

```
<script>
function onRadioClick(radio) {
  radio.form.action = radio.value;
}
function onFormSubmit(form) {
  window.location = form.action;
  return false;   
}
</script>

<form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this)">
    <label><input type="radio" name="destination" onclick="onRadioClick(this)" value="http://google.com" />Google</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="destination" onclick="onRadioClick(this)" value="http://nyt.com" />New York Times</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="destination" onclick="onRadioClick(this)" value="http://twitter.com" />Twitter</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="destination" onclick="onRadioClick(this)" value="http://microsoft.com" />Microsoft</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="destination" onclick="onRadioClick(this)" value="http://apple.com" />Apple</label><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>​
```

Comment: As an aside, this isn't "asp code". It's just html and javascript, and doesn't depend on .net at all. It's perfectly effective, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

The above client-side answer will work. However, if you want "asp code" I assume you wanted something server side. So:

1. Turn your submit button into an `asp:Button`.
2. Turn your radio buttons into an `asp:RadioButtonList`.
3. In the button's onClick event, get the value of the selected button. Then user `Response.Redirect` to redirect to that url.

Comment: I don't know anything about form building or asp. I usually configure plugins for jommla or WP to get this done, but in this instance we are not working like that. We have a windows server and most of the pages are asp. I wrongly assumed that I would need to link to an asp page to process the requests from the form. Simple is best so if I can do it client-side I will. Thanks for the help!

Comment: IIS can serve pure client side pages all day long. Have at it.